# pagePiling.js disabled mouse scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

didn't find any solution how can I disabled mouse scrolling with pagePilling.js. I need that pagePilling.js scrolling only works with menu click.

```
$('#pagepiling').pagepiling({
    menu: '#menu',
    anchors: ['page1', 'page2', 'page3', 'page4'],
    sectionsColor: ['#bfda00', '#2ebe21', '#2C3E50', '#51bec4'],
    navigation: null,
    easing: 'swing',
    afterRender: function(){
        $('video').get(0).play();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have something like this on jquery.pagepiling.js

```
$.fn.pagepiling.setAllowScrolling = function (value){
 if(value){
  $.fn.pagepiling.setMouseWheelScrolling(true);
  addTouchHandler();
 }else{
  $.fn.pagepiling.setMouseWheelScrolling(false);
  removeTouchHandler();
 }
};
```

Make this false

```
$.fn.pagepiling.setMouseWheelScrolling();
```

Comment: Working, Perfect :)